# Minimal distortion using cartogram3

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I would like to produce anamorphic maps using the QGIS plugin known as cartogram3.
Unfortunately, when I apply it to my data, the effect is minimal.
The variable has a range between 0 and 2.5 and there are 20 records.
The EPSG is 32632.
I tried also to increase the number of iterations and the % of max average error, but there are not significant variation. Do you have any suggestions?

[image: Original]

[image: distortion]

[image: range]

Comment: Please add a picture of the output

Comment: I am working with the Italian regions. There are basically no distorsions.

Comment: Still need to see it and preferably know the variation of the variable you are using

Comment: An option would be to try Scapetoad: http://scapetoad.choros.place/

Comment: What is the variable ‘File_PERSI’? If it is correlate with the area, it is normal that it won’t reaflect anything!

Comment: No, it is not correlated with the area. Moreover one value is 0!